# Set an option as selected from select dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown list having n number of options, i want on page load, option which i selected earlier should get selected in dropdown using jquery :

Here is my html code :

```
<select id="myList">
<option value="1">first</option>
<option value="2">second</option>
<option value="3">third</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="1" id="hiddenoptionid" />
```

Here is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var projectId=document.getElementById("hiddenoptionid").value;
$("#myList option[value="+projectId+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
});

$("#projectlist").on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
document.getElementById("hiddenoptionid").value=id;
location.reload(); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `$("#myList").val(projectId)` http://jsfiddle.net/xYvpE/

Answer (score 1):

You can use like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#projectlist").val($("#hiddenoptionid").val());
});
```

Note that, if you reload the page, `$("#hiddenoptionid").val()` will get reset to `1` again. If you want to retain that value, use `cookies` for that

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mentioned, i actually wants that on page reload, it will set the value which i last selected.

Comment: If i need to set the value from session, then what i have to do?